# Argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA with one string column

Tags: r

Hello I would like to calculate mean for every numeric column in my data. For now I have:

```
for(i in names(MyData)){
  avg <- mean(MyData[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
  print(avg)
}
```

but I get error like topic name because last of MyData is decisive and I have here string, is there way that ignore column with string. I also know that I can change it into numbers but I don't want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this more easily if we use `summarise_if` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
MyData %>%
     summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
```

---

In the OP's code, it is looping through each of the columns and just `print`ing the result and not storing it.  There is also a possibility that some columns are not `numeric`.  In the below code, we pre-assign a `vector` ('v1') with 0 values to store the output.  Create a logical condition with `if/else` and return the `mean` if it is `numeric` or `else` return `NA`

```
v1 <- numeric(length(MyData))
for(i in seq_along(MyData)) {
    if(is.numeric(MyData[[i]])) {
        v1[i] <- mean(MyData[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    } else {
        v1[i] <- NA_real_
     }
  }
```

---

In `base R`, this can also be done with `sapply`

```
i1 <- sapply(MyData, is.numeric)
sapply(MyData[i1], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or with `colMeans`

```
colMeans(MyData[i], na.rm = TRUE)
```